# TortoiseSVN never checks if working copy is updated to latest revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit, working-copy

Since we upgraded to TortoiseSVN 1.7, I noticed that TortoiseSVN never showed me the message that I need to update my working copy, it is never out of date.

I was at an earlier revision, I made some changes, used Commit and it went in without question.

While I was modifying, my colleague modified another file and committed it. I checked the log, and I saw the changes, but the modified file wasn't on my computer, yet my Subversion tab showed that I am on the latest revision.

I UPDATED my so called latest revision and the changes from the previous revison was downloaded (though I was on the latest revision).

How is it possible? What if my modification is dependent on what my colleague modified? I don't get it, how I was allowed to upload a modification when I am not on the latest revision. Any ideas what to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has always be the case, with all versions of SVN (and TortoiseSVN). SVN will only reject a commit if one of the modified files in the commit has been modified by someone else. since the last update of the file. It worked file by file, and not on the whole project. That's one of the well-known weaknesses of SVN.

If you want the behavior you describe, use Git.

Comment: One may consider this as a weakness, the other one will consider it as a convenient feature. It depends, in fact.

Comment: @bahrep: agreed. But in a typical software project, it's a weakness: you want to make sure that the code will compile and that the tests will pass after the commit, and SVN can't bring this guarantee.

Comment: I agree with Nizet. For me, compatibillity and reliability are top priority. In my mind there was a fading thought that in 1.6 it was different. Thanks for the clarification.